# No response after form submitted by Yii framework Cform class

Tags: php, yii

I tried to create an form by Cform class under PHP Yii framework.

An script in the controller file was as following:

```
public function actionContact() {
$model = new ContactForm;
$form = new CForm('application.views.site.contactForm',$model);
if ($form->submitted()) {
  // Done
  $this->render('done');
} else {
  $this->render('contact', array('model' => $model,'form' => $form));
}
}
```

But nothing happened after I submitted the form by click the submit button.
I guess the application did not get into this line: $this->render('done'),since $form->submitted() were false.
Please give me some hint, many thanks.

Comment: http://runnable.com/Uol3DaP7vWdtAAKc/working-with-forms-in-yii-for-php

Comment: How does the app know the form has been submitted?Since by $model = new Contact and $form = new Form('application.views.site.contactForm', $model) the model and the form had initially set to be an new object,right?